# How to iterate on a list and remove some items if keyword matches in python

Tags: python

So I have a list which contains linkedin urls of certain people. However the list contains some facebook and twitter urls as well.

```
allsocialmediaURLS= [] # this list contains 500 items, all urls.
```

How can I remove the facebook and twitter urls using python?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for querylink in allsocialmedialinks:
    query = querylink
    stopwords = ['facebook', 'twitter']
    querywords = query.split()

    resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
    result = ' '.join(resultwords)

    print(result)
```

Output: Nothing changes. In result I still get all the urls from the originalal lsocialmedialinks list.

Comment: Could you add some exemplary inputs for `allsocialmedialinks` together with the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Could you share what ```allsocialmediaURLS``` looks like ?

Comment: What does `query = querylink` do? You just provide another name for querylink - whatfor?

Comment: How do you propose to handle this URL:- https://www.myhost.com/api/twitter/v1.0/

Comment: General remark: I don't think `in` works particularly well with arrays. Sets would be a better solution if you just need to check for existence. `query = querylink` makes no sense. Also you can't split links without passing delimiters as they are not space-delimited. If you want to do it properly, you'd need to get the TLD alone, maybe there is a regex for that. If you just split at `.` you may also remove subdomains containing the stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

per default the `split()` method used in `querywords = query.split()` splits by whitespace. So since you URLs probably don't containt whitespaces, the array is not split and therefore it does not match your stopwords.

I would suggest to split by `/` or `.` depending on how your urls actually look like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a link is in the format `https://www.socialmedia.com/in/someone-42/`, you splitting by a space, will not give you a list with more than 1 element, because there's no spaces to begin with.

Try splitting by `.` and filter out the links you don't want. for example:

```
for querylink in allsocialmedialinks:
    query = querylink
    stopwords = ['facebook', 'twitter']
    querywords = query.split('.')
   
    if any([stopword in querywords for stopword in stopwords]):
        continue
    result.append('.'.join(querywords))
```

The above code will filter out the stopwords links if and only if, the social media names are explicitly mentioned and have a preceding and tailing `.` for the keyword like in `www.twitter.com/some_tweet`

Comment: What does `query = querylink` do? You just provide another name for querylink - what for? This: `if any([stopword in querywords for stopword in stopwords]):` needs to create the full list - this: `if any(stopword in querywords for stopword in stopwords):` can evaluate and leave as soon as any stopword matches which may be much faster

Comment: querylink returns a url which is stored in `allsocialmedialinks`. in `allsocialmedialinks` there are 50 urls I iterate over them and if they are not linkedin url i want to push them out.

Comment: @Patric, note that the code is made to replicate OP's as much as possible, and they create an alias for `querylink`. You're right about using `any(stopword in querywords for stopword in stopwords)` over the current loop, please feel free to edit the answer to make it better!

Comment: Most links won't contain www, so as of now you neither match `https://facebook.com` nor do you cover cases in which `facebook` is a subdomain. OP wasn't clear on the latter though

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion does not remove URLs from the original list. Instead it creates a new list. Furthermore, it tries to remove ambiguities by (effectively) validating all URLs. See output after the code for further explanation.

```
import re


def removeURLs(myURLS, ignore):
    rv = []
    cre = re.compile(
        '^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?')
    for url in myURLS:
        if (m := cre.search(url)) and (g := m.groups()[3]):
            if any(i.lower() in g.lower() for i in ignore):
                continue
        rv.append(url)
    return rv


URLS = ['www.facebook.com',
        'http://www.twitter.com', 'https://www.bbc.co.uk']
IGNORE = ['facebook', 'Twitter']

print(removeURLs(URLS, IGNORE))
```

The output of this will be:-

['www.facebook.com', 'https://www.bbc.co.uk']

Note that 'www.facebook.com' is included because it is not, by strict definition, a URL

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function which checks for your stopwords and returns the urls without those words.

```
def remove_stopwords(urls, stopwords, index=0):
    tmp_list = [i for i in urls if stopwords[index] not in i]
    if index == len(stopwords) - 1:
        return tmp_list
    return remove_stopwords(tmp_list, stopwords, index=index+1)
```

To test this, here are some random urls:

```
import numpy as np
stopwords = ['facebook', 'twitter']
rnd = np.random.default_rng(12345)
urls1 = ['https://linkedin.com/in/' + ''.join(i) + '' for i in rnd.choice([i for i in 'adbcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'], [5, 10])]
urls2 = ['https://twitter.com/' + ''.join(i) + '' for i in rnd.choice([i for i in 'adbcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'], [5, 7])]
urls3 = ['https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=' + ''.join(i) for i in rnd.choice([str(i) for i in np.arange(9)], [5, 10])]
urls = urls1 + urls2 + urls3
urls

# Output
#['https://linkedin.com/in/rfuhduqrzj',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/vhopddfrpy',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/sfxysrcbgk',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/dwlrdhcstd',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/sbjetilllg',
# 'https://twitter.com/ovmdacb',
# 'https://twitter.com/bcpuwqp',
# 'https://twitter.com/hyqsswr',
# 'https://twitter.com/ynnfynm',
# 'https://twitter.com/hgqloqx',
# 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=2684223527',
# 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=3000532504',
# 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=5013283517',
# 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=1643442128',
# 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=2627451546']


remove_stopwords(urls, stopwords)
# Output

# ['https://linkedin.com/in/rfuhduqrzj',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/vhopddfrpy',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/sfxysrcbgk',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/dwlrdhcstd',
# 'https://linkedin.com/in/sbjetilllg']
```

This of course assumes that your urls are always of some people like you mentioned in OP. Hence this will fail if your url is something like `https://linkedin.com/in/somefacebookuser`.